# Error -> Colon operands must be in the range of the data type. No sense

Tags: matlab

In the code below image index range only accept to deal with `int16` however I can't find a proper explanation for this case. In the same code, you can notice if I change the data type to `int8` for same value error will present.

```
K>> t2 = int8(t)

t2 =

  int8

   45

K>> I2 = flt_rot(t:end,:);
K>> I2 = flt_rot(t2:end,:);
Error using  : 
Colon operands must be in the range of the data type.
```

Why did this happen?

Comment: How large is your matrix? If `end` is a value larger than 127, it won't fit in an `int8`.

Comment: my matrix is 200X300 but the index value is only 45. it should be enough to store the index. isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To understand this problem, first a little background:

MATLAB has a rather unique behavior with respect to numeric values of different types. Originally, MATLAB only used double-precision floating point values (`double`). At some point it became possible to store arrays of other types, but it was not possible to use those for much. It was not until MATALB 7.0 or so that arithmetic with non-doubles was possible (I'm a bit hazy exactly when that was introduced). And these operations are still a bit "awkward", if you will.

For one, MATLAB does not allow operations with mixed types:

```
>> int8(4)+int16(6)
Error using  + 
Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.
```

Note that error message: "scalar doubles". The one exception to mixed types is that any operation is possible if one of the operands is a scalar double.

Another thing to note is that any operation with a non-double type and a double type results in values of the non-double type:

```
>> int8(4)+6
ans =
  int8
   10
```

The color operator (`:`) is no exception:

```
>> int8(4):6
ans =
  1×3 int8 row vector
   4   5   6
```

Finally, the last thing to know to understand this problem is that `end` is a function that returns a double scalar value (yes, it really is a function, albeit a very special one, see `help end`).

If you have an array `flt_rot` that is 200x300, `end` in the first index returns 200. That is, `flt_rot(t2:end,:)` is the same as `flt_rot(t2:200,:)`. Since `t2` is a `int8` type:

```
>> t2=int8(45);
>> t2:200
Error using  : 
Colon operands must be in the range of the data type.
```

The solution to your problem is to not use numeric values of type other than `double` for anything except in large data sets where the amount of memory used matters. For indexing, using an integer is not going to give you any speedup over using doubles, but will give you lots of other problems. There is a reason that the default values are always doubles.

This will work:

```
I2 = flt_rot(double(t2):end,:);
```